# can I synchronize the timestamp of camera and imu on the Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera

as we know , the camera system and imu system on android (include ndk) use the event callback methods with timestamp , but I find the timestamp between then they are not the same , I have thought they all use the android system, am I wrong ? 
is there any way to synchronize them?

Comment: as I know , the timestamp is a longlong data for nanosecond....

Comment: Any update on this front?